# Generic functions that take structs with

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a generic function. I have the following code:

```
struct Car {
    id: u8,
    wheels: u8,
    seatbelt: bool,
}

struct Motorcycle {
    id: u8,
    wheels: u8,
    helmet: bool,

trait Vehicle {}
impl Vehicle for Car {}
impl Vehicle for Motorcycle {}

fn vehicle_info<T>(vehicle: T) 
where
    T: Vehicle,
{
    println!("{} {}", vehicle.id, vehicle.wheels)
}
```

The compiler gives me `error: no field id on type T.`
Now the question is how do I promise to the compiler in the trait that all structs passed into the function have these certain fields?

Comment: Take the time to read [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html). When you declare `T: Vehicle` this means that you can use any data of type `T` only through what was declared *inside* the `Vehicle` trait. Here `Vehicle` is empty so you cannot do anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rust, traits cannot have fields [for now](https://github.com/nikomatsakis/fields-in-traits-rfc). You can provide access to a field from a trait with a method (commonly referred to as *getters*):

```rust
trait Vehicle {
    fn get_id(&self) -> u8;
    fn get_wheels(&self) -> u8;
}
```

You can implement the trait by simply returning the associated field:

```rust
impl Vehicle for Car {
    fn get_id(&self) -> u8 {
        self.id
    }
    
    fn get_wheels(&self) -> u8 {
        self.wheels
    }
}
```

And now you can access the fields of a `Vehicle` through the getter methods:

```rust
fn vehicle_info<T>(vehicle: T) 
where
    T: Vehicle,
{
    println!("{} {}", vehicle.id(), vehicle.wheels())
}
```

Comment: Please search for potential duplicates before answering and then vote to close the question instead of answering duplicates.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that one